# Is there any performance difference between $emit event and casual function call in ng-click?

Tags: angularjs

```
<script>
  angular.app('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
     $scope.$on('foo', function(evt, msg) {
         alert(msg); 
     });
     $scope.foo = function(msg) { 
         alert(msg); 
     };
    });
</script>
<div ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="ctrl">
<button ng-click="foo('some msg')">Call</button>
<button ng-click="$emit('foo')">Emit</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Is there a significant performance different between two cases? Which case should I usually go by?

Comment: I found out this, it actually won't answer your question but can be a start: [Using rootscope emit As A Performance Optimization In AngularJS](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2807-using-rootscope-emit-as-a-performance-optimization-in-angularjs.htm)